# Caught a shiny Bellsprout, will evolving it to Victreebel lower its trade value?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-series

I caught a shiny Bellsprout and before I level it up and evolve it, I was hoping to clarify whether or not it would be wise to keep him as a Bellsprout.

Comment: What game in the Pokémon series is this?

Comment: Pokemon X, but Shiny of Bellsprout has existed in previous versions.

Comment: It will stay shiny if you evolve it.

Comment: @shanodin I think the question is more of whether a shiny Bellsprout is more "valuable" than a shiny Victreebel.

Answer (score 2):

In my eyes, a Shiny Bellsprout is worth more than a Shiny Victreebell mainly because if you plan on trading it for another Shiny, the receiver can choose to evolve it or not, depending on if they like Bellsprout or Victreebell more.

Value means nothing though if you plan on keeping it.

There is no set value on any Pokemon. The "value" is set by the owner or the buyer. If the buyer wants it bad, then it is worth more, but if they could care less for it, then its value lowers.